# Remove time stamp from the date

Tags: apex, query, date, convert

I want assign a date value into a WHERE clause of query
This is my date

```
Date myDate = System.Today().AddDays(Integer.valueOf(Deal_Expiration_Batch_Settings__c.getInstance().Expire_Notification_Prior_Days__c));
```

And this is my WHERE clause

```
 String strQuery = ' SELECT Id
            + ' FROM bDeal__c WHERE End_Date__c =:' + myDate)';
```

Here **myDate** is retrun the value as **2018-06-01 00:00:00**
But End_Date__c in the query is returning as **2018-06-01**

So I am getting an error **System.QueryException: unexpected token: '2018-06-01'**

How to resolve this. Please anyone help me.

I have tried to format the date using myDate.format() method. But it is returning the values as string. I want a Date type value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't need `'` symbol to enclose `myDate` variable.

```
Date myDate = System.Today().AddDays(Integer.valueOf(Deal_Expiration_Batch_Settings__c.getInstance().Expire_Notification_Prior_Days__c));
String strQuery = 'SELECT Id FROM bDeal__c WHERE End_Date__c = :myDate';
```

and in this case dynamic soql variable binding is used.

Answer (score 2):

Apex supports the binding of data into static SOQL (via the `:` character) meaning in general you do not need to concatenate strings to create queries.

So in your case:

```
Date myDate = ...;

bDeal__c[] deals = [SELECT Id FROM bDeal__c WHERE End_Date__c :myDate];
```

*Static* SOQL has the advantage that it is syntax checked by the compiler (including that the objects and fields exist) and is easier to get right as there is less clutter in the code. It also automatically avoids the risk of [SOQL Injection](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_security_tips_soql_injection.htm).

*Dynamic* SOQL based on building strings as you are doing is only occasionally necessary where you want to vary the query in away that can't be done through bind variables.